# Catch an error at nginx reload

Tags: bash, shell, nginx

I have a bash script that's make some operation on nginx's virtualhosts. I would like to know how to catch error if nginx not reloading correctly (`nginx reload`).

I think to use `nginx -t` but i don't know to intercept error in a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

nginx -t returns 0 when he reloads, and something different when not

```
hbranciforte# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
hbranciforte# echo $? 
0
hbranciforte# vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 

zsh: suspended  vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
hbranciforte# nginx -t                 
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "siiendfile" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:16
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
hbranciforte# echo $?                  
1
```

So you are able to do something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$( nginx -t )

reload_code=$?

if [ $reload_code -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "conf is correct"
else
  echo "conf is not correct"
fi
```

but remember that -t will just check configuration, if you really want to reload your configuration you have to send

```
nginx -s reload

  #!/bin/bash

output=$( nginx -s reload )

reload_code=$?

if [ $reload_code -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "reloaded"
else
  echo "could not reload, exit with $reload_code"
fi
```